# spring boot mail ignoring application.properties

Tags: java, spring, maven, email, spring-boot

I'm new to spring and I'm having some issues sending mail using spring boot mail.
I'm defining the user, password and everything else in my application.properties file, but spring is trying to send the email using my pc username (usuario@usuario-Inspiron-3647).

**application.properties**

```
#spring boot properties
#Mon Oct 02 08:41:37 EDT 2017
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc\:postgresql\://localhost/database

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate

#Spring Mail Config
spring.mail.host = email-ssl.com.br
spring.mail.port = 587
spring.mail.username = teste@teste.com
spring.mail.password = teste
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable = true
```

**EmailServiceImpl**

```
@Component
public class EmailServiceImpl implements EmailService {

@Autowired
public JavaMailSender emailSender;

@Override
public boolean sendSimpleMessage(String to, String subject, String text, String cc, String bcc) {
    try {
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setTo(to);
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(text);
        message.setCc(cc);
        message.setBcc(bcc);
        emailSender.send(message);

        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

This is the exception I get

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 504 5.5.2 <usuario@usuario-Inspiron-3647>: Sender address rejected: need fully-qualified address
; message exception details (1) are:
Failed message 1:
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 504 5.5.2 <usuario@usuario-Inspiron-3647>: Sender address rejected: need fully-qualified address
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.spring.teste</groupId>
    <artifactId>webservice</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <jjwt.version>0.6.0</jjwt.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement />
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Data -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot Tomcat -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- PostgreSQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson JSON Processor -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.8</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Everything else is working properly but I can't find why it's not getting the email config info from application.properties and I wasn't able to find anything similar googling it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved adding to application.properties:

```
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.from=teste@teste.com
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `Sender address rejected: need fully-qualified address` wants you to set email sender address for your message:

```
SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
message.setFrom("some@email.com"); 

...
```

Comment: I already tried that. It didn't work. It still tries to authenticate using my desktop username, thus I still get the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

Note that even though it's not mandatory to provide the from address, many SMTP servers would reject such messages. So it is necessary to add the from.